# Facebook API: How to specify friend in stream post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is trying to post messages about a person's friend.

```
    $returnObject = $facebook->api(
        '/me/feed',
        'POST',
        array(
            'link' => 'http://www.collabra.cc/i-appreciate-you/',
            'message' => 'I appreciate [Friend Name] for $appreciation'
        )
    );
```

How do I get it so that when it is posted, the friend's name is shown in Blue highlight and the friend is notified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph or FQL API **don't** allow developers to do this.

However, that can be done using the **Open Graph** API. But, Open Graph is not only about code, it is also a lot of configuration. Please read the following:

- [Bringing Mention Tagging to Open Graph - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/)
- [Using Actions - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions), "mentionning friends" section.

---

> ### Mentionning Friends
>
> In contrast to action tagging of friends, mention tagging lets people tag up to ten friends in a message
> included along with the Open Graph story. Mentioned friends are
> notified and if they have tag review enabled they'll be given the
> option to approve or reject the story from their own timeline. The tag
> will link to that friend's timeline.
>
> The first step is to enable both tags and messages capabilities for
> your action type. This requires an additional approval process before
> it can be used by anyone who's not a developer or tester of your app.
>
> Once you've enabled that, you simply add a message parameter to your
> action publishing call, where message is a string of text created by
> the person using your app. This message cannot be prefilled and any
> apps that do so will not be approved. Within this message, you can
> mention friends by using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> @[userID or userName]
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> POST /me/cookbook:eat?
>   recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&
>   place=http://www.example.com/places/123/&
>   tags=123456&
>   message=You should really try this recipe @[123457] and @[https://www.facebook.com/123458]&
>   access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
> ```